# jquery autocomplete, parsing data

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, autocomplete

I use a jquery autocomplete:

the page whatever returns:

```
Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object ]
```

Object has id:INTEGER and value:STRING

```
ele.autocomplete({
    minLength: 1,               
    delay: 150,             
    source: function(request, response) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "whatever",
            data: {                         
                term: request.term
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                 response(data);                                                

                /* this actually works id is correctly logged
                data.forEach(function(element) {
                     console.log(element.id);
                });*/


            }
         });
     },             
     select: function(e, ui) {
        //do i have to do something here? (i guess)
     }
 });
```

What I want to accomplish (and I am incapable to do) is: when I select a value from the autocomplete menu, the input (ele) value is changed to the corresponding id, while it's "text" remains the string value.

What can I do? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, just for future reference if someone needs it:

```
 response(data); is not ok

 response($.map(data, function(item) {
      return {
         value: item.id,  //set the value property with id integer
         label: item.value  //set the label property with "value" string 
       };
 }));
```

then

```
select: function(e, ui) {       //when selecting an element from the list
    var keyid = ui.item.value;  //get value wich now contains id
    var keylab = ui.item.label; //and the label wich contains the string
    console.log(keyid + ' - ' + keylab); //do what you have to do
}
```